# How to return all database rows with certain field value

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Hey, I have a database table called "projects" with the fields 'id', 'locationid', 'name' and 'year'.  I query the database to retrieve all the values and store them in $data, before passing them into the relevant view.

In what part of the website, I have created a timeline (made of list items generated with a foreach).  In this timeline, I was to associate projects with their corresponding 'year' value.  So under 1999, I would find all the projects for 1999.

Right now I have an ugly hacked solution where inside the foreach which I use to generate the timeline I have ANOTHER foreach that goes through the projects table and checks to see if the 'year' field matches the current timeline year, and if so adds it.

Is there a more elegant way to query the $data I passed into the view (and therefore database field values) based on finding specific strings?

Essentially, if I could write it how I want to express it, I'm looking for something like this:

```
<?php foreach $year_range as $timeline_year : ?>
   <div class="projects_menu">
      <?php foreach $projects WHERE $projects->$year EQUAL $timeline_year : ?>
      <?php echo $projects->$name ?>
      <?php endforeach ?>
   </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Why do you write a new set of php tags for each line of code?

Comment: @MrXexxed It seems to be standard practice in a lot of *view* (V in MVC) files.

Comment: CodeIgniter doesn't like it when you don't.  Or that's what I was taught.

Comment: CodeIgniter shouldn't care (unless it itself parses your PHP and checks, which I highly doubt). It still looks cleaner in a view in my opinion, and the speed difference is generally negligible.

Comment: Short tags for selection statements are generally used when HTML is being output. If you are only producing PHP, they aren't really needed. It's still just preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but it seems like you could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE ($condition) ORDER BY YEAR ASC, name ASC
```

And then simply output the results in PHP:

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    /* output $project */
}
```

or

```
foreach ($year_range as $year) {
    /* output timeline, inserting projects if any occur in that year */
}
```

`$condition` might be something like:

```
projects.year >= $start_year AND projects.year <= $end_year
```

or

```
projects.year IN ($year_range)
```

or

```
projects.year IN ($year_range) and project.name LIKE '%$search_string%'
```

You'll have to be more specific about "finding specific strings" as I'm not sure where that would come into play in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A complete dynamic solution would be to:

first sql query

```
SELECT `year`
FROM `projects`
GROUP BY `year`
ORDER BY `year` ASC
```

Then loop through that

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
echo '<div class="projects_menu">';
echo $row['year'].' Projects';
$q2="SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `year`='{$year}' ORDER BY `name`";
//db connection $r2
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2)) {
 echo $row2['name'];
}
echo '</div>';
}
```

So that way it doesn't matter how many years you have to get.

Im pretty sure this is what you were after

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into CodeIgniter's [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) syntax? Maybe something like:

```
$this->db->select("*")->from("projects")->where("year <=", $date);
$query = $this-<db->get();
```

That should return all of the records that are less than or equal to a $data argument.